# Prove that for $\phi \in D$, $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{n}(x)\phi (x)\,dx=1$

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, limits, distribution-theory

Let defined sequence function :

$$f_{n}(x)=\begin{cases}1-\frac{|x|}{n},|x|<n\\0,\operatorname{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Find

> $\lim_{n\to +\infty}f_{n}(x)$

Then prove that for $\phi \in D$

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{n}(x)\phi (x)dx$=1$

My solution for first question

Take limit of $f_{n}$ so

$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(1-\frac{|x|}{n}\right)=1$

But $|x|<+\infty$

So what's the limit of $f_{n}(x)$ ?

Comment: It should be $|x|<n$ in the definition of $f_n$, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes Sir @md2perpe thank you

Comment: There seems to be more errors in your text. Should it really be $\lim_{n\to +\infty} \int f_{n}(x) \, \phi (x) \, dx$? (By the way, you missed the integral sign in that formula.) Perhaps you are missing a factor in the definition of $f_n$?

Answer (score 1):

Fix $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and notice that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x| > n$ we have
$$f_n(x) = 1- \frac{|x|}n \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 1$$
so $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) = 1$.

Your second claim seems to be that for all $\phi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ holds
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_n(x)\phi(x)\,dx = 1$$
but this is false e.g. for $\phi \equiv 0$.

Comment: $\phi$ never get $0$ because $\phi\in D%

Comment: Isn't $D$ the space of smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}$ with compact support, i.e. $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: OK sir I understand you , what about second $b)$ how I find it ?

Comment: @EllenEllen The second claim seems to be false in general. Are you sure you wrote it correctly?

Comment: Yes Sir @mechanodroid its from a book!

Comment: @EllenEllen. Can you scan or take a photograph of the exercise in the book?